# Matlab profiler text is not rendered properly in Ubuntu

Tags: matlab, ubuntu, profiler

I am accessing the MATLAB on a server by X2Go on Ubuntu 14.04. The server itself runs on CentOs 6.7.

While running the MATLAB profiler, the text does not get rendered properly.
When I access the server on Windows, the issue does not happen. I have attached a screenshot of it.

Is there a fix for this issue?

[image]

Comment: And is the 141 seconds a correct answer??

Comment: Yes, 141 is correct. However, what bothers me is the line instead of then function name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Though this comes a bit late: I had the exact same issue and I think it's related to Intel's graphics drivers (HD 530 on a Skylake i7 here). On my other computer with an NVIDIA GPU I never had this issue.

I fixed it by enabling font antialiasing in Matlab:

Preferences -> Fonts -> [x] Use antialiasing to smooth desktop fonts (requires MATLAB restart)